# Falcon 9 exhaust color

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, atmospheric-science

We've seen quite a few Falcon 9 launches over the last years, but couple of days ago (at the NASA DART / Falcon 9 launch from Vandenberg SFB at 10:21pm local time, on Nov 23) we noticed something that we have never seen before. As the vehicle gained altitude the exhaust color changed from the typical orange (left side of the image) to a very distinct two-colored clear-blue/deep-red plume (right). This was a couple of minutes in the flight. The time between the two images is less than a minute.

[image: Exhaust plume color change]

The color is not an image processing artifact - it was clearly visible through the optical viewfinder of the camera and through binoculars.

Ok, I get that the color of a flame depends on what's burning and how hot, emission lines, etc, etc. But why the change - why orange first and separate blue/red a bit higher up? What changed, I assume, is the pressure and speed but not much else. This was way before MECO - it's not like I captured the moment the engine was shutting off.

Does anybody have a clue what exactly are the orange, red, and blue spectral lines?

Comment: Not sure, but might imagine that this is a matter of rayleigh scattering through the athmosphere (making he sun seem red when it sets), rather than different spectral lines

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is most prominent just before sunrise or just after sunset. It happens because as the rocket goes higher and higher, the sun's rays might interfere and cause the exhaust color to change. If the exhaust color was red at the beginning, as it would go higher and higher, it's color might have changed to whitish color because some amount of sunlight would have been falling on the exhaust, causing it change it's color (we would see the difference in color but it's actual color would remain same. We see different color because of refraction of light or it could also be [Rayleigh Scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering).

Comment: I've seen the effect you are talking about and this is not it. If the launch is shortly after sunset then yes, the condensation trail (not the exhaust itself) changes color from red towards yellow and white with altitude, as it gets exposed to red and then white light from the sun. The thing is, then the color varies for altitude - it is first red, then yellow, then white; here two colors are visible at the same time.